# Hotkey in Intellij IDEA for action

Tags: java, intellij-idea, linux-mint

When I will click Left Alt + Left Mouse Button I want to see evaluation for code, but I can't find name of this action in *Settings->Keymap*. Can help me?

[image]

P.S. I use Linux Mint OS

Comment: [This one](http://i.imgur.com/mQTe4mI.png)?

Comment: @CrazyCoder, yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action name is **Quick Evaluate Expression**:

[image: quick evaluate]